# Showing default option selected in Mat select - When mat options values are depend upon parent dropdown

Tags: angular, angular7

I have two mat-selects, let say dropdown-1 and dropdown-2 ,Options of Dropdown 2 are depend upon what user choose in Dropdown-1.

here, I want to show when user choose any value from dropdown 1 , it should  display relative values in dropdown -2 (its working) and default option of ALL shoud be remain selected (All should not be displayed on page load, once user click in dropdown-1 then and then it should come only).

```
<mat-form-field>
       <mat-select  (optionSelected)="productSelect($event.value)">
         <mat-option *ngIf="products" >All</mat-option>
          <mat-option *ngFor="let product of products" 
  [value]="product.name">
            {{ product.name }}
          </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
      </mat-form-field>
```

Please help on  this .

Comment: Do you have some sample data to work with?

Comment: its simple you can assume ..state ..city scenerio....where on choosing of state ...cities would be populated and default selection will remain ALL CITIES in city dropdown box.

Answer (score 1):

Add [value]="" to the `<mat-option>All</mat-option>`, then, when your fill "products", equal the mat-select to ''. You should use [(ngModel)] or Reactive Forms to give value in an easy way

see a fool example in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kxufby?file=app/select-overview-example.html)

```
  <mat-select [(ngModel)]="food" (selectionChange)="getKind()">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let f of foods" [value]="f.value">
      {{f.viewValue}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>

  <mat-select [(ngModel)]="kind">
    <mat-option value="">All</mat-option>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let t of kinds" [value]="kinds">
      {{t}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>

getKind()
  {
    this.kinds=[];
    switch (this.food)
    {
      case '0':
         this.kinds=['cow','pig']
         break;
      case '1':
         this.kinds=['four cheese','pinaple']
         break;
      case '2':
         this.kinds=['vegetal']

    }
    this.kind='';
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maintain a `cityOptions` array for the Options to be displayed in the second dropdown:

```
cityOptions = [];
```

Then set it whenever state changes:

```
stateChanged(stateName: string) {
  this.cityOptions = this.cities.filter(city => city.state === stateName);
}
```

Your template should do this for the bindings:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>States</mat-label>
  <mat-select (selectionChange)="stateChanged($event.value)">
    <mat-option value="" disabled>All</mat-option>
    <mat-option 
      *ngFor="let state of states" 
      [value]="state.name">
      {{ state.name }}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>

<br>

<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Cities</mat-label>
  <mat-select>
    <mat-option value="" disabled>All</mat-option>
    <mat-option 
      *ngFor="let city of cityOptions" 
      [value]="city.name">
      {{ city.name }}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hztu4q?file=app/select-overview-example.html) for your ref.